# Infinite-time, Path-Dependent Expected Value of an Orstein-Uhlenbeck process

Tags: stochastic-processes, asymptotics, stochastic-differential-equations

I am dealing with an Orstein-Uhlenbeck process $X_t$ with its stochastic differential equation being

$$dX_t=(\mu-X_t)dt+\sigma dW_t.$$

I want to show

$$\mathbb{E}\left[\frac{|X_\infty|}{\int_{0}^{\infty}f(X_s)ds}\right]=0,$$

where $f(x)=\mathbb{1}\{x\leq a\}$ for some $a>\mu$. Is there a simple way to prove this? Thanks!

Comment: What is $X_{\infty}$?

Comment: @S.Surace $X_\infty$ is $\lim_{t\rightarrow\infty}X_t$.

Answer (score 3):

Suppose that $\mu=0$ --- for simplicity.

By Cauchy-Schwarz, 
\begin{align*}
\mathbb{E} \left\{  \frac{ |X_{\infty}|}{\int_0^{\infty} f(X_s) ds} \right\} \le \sqrt{\mathbb{E} \left\{ X_{\infty}^2 \right\} \mathbb{E} \left\{ \left( \frac{1}{\int_0^{\infty} f(X_s) ds}\right)^2 \right\}  } \;.  \tag{1}
\end{align*}
Since $X$ is ergodic with non-normalized stationary density $e^{-\frac{x^2}{\sigma^2}} $, $$
\mathbb{E} \left\{ X_{\infty}^2 \right\} = \frac{\sigma^2}{2} \;, \tag{2}
$$
and  , $$
\lim_{t \to \infty}  \frac{1}{t} \int_0^t f(X_s) ds  = \frac{1}{2} \left( 1 + \operatorname{erf}\left( \frac{a}{\sigma} \right) \right)  \;.
\tag{3}
$$
Combining (1), (2) and (3) yields the desired result.

Comment: Sorry but can you explain the last step a bit more? (3) implies that $\frac{1}{\int_{0}^{\infty}f(X_s)ds}=0$ almost surely, and that does not necessarily mean $\mathbb{E}\left\{\left(\frac{1}{\int_{0}^{\infty}f(X_s)ds}\right)^2\right\}=0$, right?

Comment: Actually $\frac{1}{\int_{0}^{\infty}f(X_s)ds}=0$ almost surely does not imply $\lim_{t\rightarrow\infty}\mathbb{E}\left\{\left(\frac{1}{\int_{0}^{t}f(X_s)ds}\right)^2\right\}=0$, but what about $\mathbb{E}\left\{\left(\frac{1}{\int_{0}^{\infty}f(X_s)ds}\right)^2\right\}$?

Comment: Hinit: use limit rules.